# %USERPROFILE% in registry

Tags: windows, powershell, regedit

I am scripting a solution that requires passing %USERPROFILE% to the registry in local_machine. For example

```
DotJetFolder=%USERPROFILE%\JetFolder
```

But it seems like registry doesn't understand this format. Looking for ideas on how to implement it. This for an RDS solution where we can't pre-determine the user profile.

Is there any way to pass this sort of variable to the registry.

Comment: The registry can store just about any string you want. It's unclear from your question how you intend to set this value. If it's in a `.reg` file, you need to quote the value, and you may need to explicitly specify the type as `REG_EXPAND_SZ` if the application expects that. If you need to pre-expand the variable, it depends on whatever code you're using now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the value as a REG_EXPAND_SZ value if you want environment variables in the string to be expanded when Windows reads the value. In PowerShell the creation of such a value would look somewhat like this:

```bsh
$key   = 'HKLM:\some\where'
$name  = 'DotJetFolder'
$value = '%USERPROFILE%\JetFolder'

Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name $name -Value $value -Type ExpandString
```

Comment: thanks got this error: A parameter cannot be found that matches -Type

Comment: @mri.o Then you did something wrong. Please update your question with the actual code you were running and the complete error message.

Comment: The registry API does not automatically expand environment variables in a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value. This type is a hint for the application to expand the string via [`ExpandEnvironmentStringsW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsw) or [`ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUserW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/userenv/nf-userenv-expandenvironmentstringsforuserw).

Comment: @eryksun That may be true, but I doubt that it's relevant for the question at hand. We won't know for certain until the OP decides to actually show their code, though.

Comment: It is unquestionably true and quite different from the statement "if you want environment variables in the string to be expanded when Windows reads the value". `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values will not be expanded when the value is read. Some APIs do expand them, such as `CreateEnvironmentBlock`. But if the registry API itself did this, we'd have no way to read and modify the unexpanded value.

Comment: Point taken, but still considered irrelevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to have a sub for "%USERPROFILE%"

```
$temp = "$env:USERPROFILE" + "\Jet"
Write-Host $temp
```

Hope it Helps!
BR